# What do Mbps and Kbps represent in Task Manager Performance Tab?

Tags: windows, networking, task-manager

What do Mbps or Kbps represent in Task Manager performance Tab?

**Example of Kbps being used**
[image: Please See Attached]

I often get confused by this measure, since it sometimes shows 15.0 Mbps in Task Manager - however, the actual download speed is merely 1.5 Mb/s in uTorrent or IDM etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last sentence in your question indicates that you do know that these values are actually your network transfer speeds. Your question appears to be about the discrepancy that you mentioned.

There are two reasons:

1. IDM and uTorrent actually report the speed in kilo**bytes** per seconds and mega**bytes** per second (K**B**/s or M**B**/s) while Task Manager shows kilo**bit** per second and mega**bits** per second (K**b**ps and M**b**ps). A byte consists of eight bits, hence, expect Task Manager to report values that are at least eight times bigger.
2. Task Manager shows the total bytes transferred, which include those spent in datalink frames, IP packet, TCP segment, application layer overhead and flow-control communications like [ACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgement_(data_networks)). uTorrent and IDM show only bytes pertaining raw payload. Imagine the difference between your lean weight and the weight of you along your clothes, watch, backpack, etc. You will get a good idea.

Comment: Do we know whether Task Manager shows kib/s (kibibits/s, 1024 based) or kb/s (1000 based)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about Mbps ( Mega Bits per second) and MBps (Mega Bytes Per Second). As 1 Byte = 8 Bits ,thats why you are seeing 15Mbps while utorrent shows 1.5MBps.

Answer (score 1):

*X*bps means *X*Bit per second. Likewise, *X*b/s also means *X*Bits per second. The only way unambiguously indicate *X*Bytes instead of *X*Bits is to write a capital B (and not use “Bps”): *X*B/s.

15 Mbps / 8 * 1000<sup>2</sup> / 1024<sup>2</sup> = 1.788 MiB/s

So it’s roughly correct if we keep in mind overhead and miscellaneous traffic.